# Alternative to "rows UNBOUNDED PRECEDING" in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am working on a conversion of a series of teradata statements to SQL Server 2005.

Everything is ok until we came across this :

```
select 
    CODE, _year, _month, _day, product,
    sum(DAILY_AMMOUNT) over (partition by CODE, _year, _month, product 
                             order by _day ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as DAY_AMM 
from ...
```

As you for sure know there is no **ROWS** in SQL Server 2005.

I know that in some cases I could replace it with `RANGE`, but I don't have access to the teradata database to check if this is indeed the case.

Any idea on how I can replace the sum to be sure that the result will be matching?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't have a window for a `SUM()` in SQL Server 2005. You're down to looking for alternative ways to do cumulative sums (they're messy to say the least). PS: SQL Server 2005 will be out of support real soon... consider upgrading to SQL Server 2014, you won't have to change statements like that.

Comment: that is what i was scare of... 

thanks !